# Spring projects get database configuration from other Spring Project

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I would like to have different projects that consume the same database configuration from other spring project, I have the next Database configuration in each project with the application.properties too:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("xxxx");
            sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return sessionFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource(){
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");      
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:teradata://xxxx");  


            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean(name = "properties")
        public Properties hibernateProperties(){
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect");
            return properties;
        }




}
```

I suppose that the sessionFactory() method should be in each project, but the others could be in a DatabaseConfig project. I would like to use rest if it's necessary between them.

Is it possible? 
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of rolling your own, why not simply use Spring Boot (looks like you are trying to reinvent auto configuration yourself). Also don't use `DriverManagerDataSource` for production databases, use a proper connection pool like HikariCP).

Comment: I didn't get what you said about using Spring Boot, this is an app that uses @SpringBootApplication and as I have to connect to a db, I made this configuration. Are you saying that this is not necessary at all?. I followed your advice, I'm using HikariCP now but I still having the same doubt as before.

Comment: You don't need this configuration Spring Boot configures a `DataSource` and hibernate for you. Your config class bypasses what Spring Boot does. If you want to use a shared configuration due to shared config, use a configuration server instead.  But the at least your configuration class isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the configuration server of spring.

Answer (score 0):

Do you share the same database and perform same operations? If so, implement it as dao and simply include it as jar in every project, that needs it.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but the problem with that is that if for any reason the db configuration changes then I''ll have an old jar and I'll  be force to update it in each project.

Comment: If you manage your packages with maven, you just have to update the topmost parent with new version. not much work there